# Lazy mutual recursive evaluation of Polysemy expressions

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, haskell-polysemy

*NB*: I don't think the problem here is with Polysemy *per se*.

### The Goal:

I'm trying to write a single-thread simulation of multiple parties communicating synchronously. More specifically, the goal is to write the program that one party will run* in some effect system** and have a pure function that will simulate the multiple parties all running their programs together. The output of this simulation should be a representation of all the messages sent (or received) by each party***.

<sub>*All parties will run the same program.</sub>
<sub>**[Polysemy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/polysemy) is what I know.</sub>
<sub>***And each party's respective return value, although that's not really important.</sub>

### Setup:

We can simplify a little and suppose there are only two parties. For this context I wrote a simple `Pair` functor; for the real system I expect to use fixed-length vectors.

The particular effects we're interested in are `Input` and `Output`.
`output $ Pair a1 a2` means that "the party in question" sends `a1` to party #1 and `a2` to party #2.
`Pair b1 b2 <- input` means that "the party in question" receives `b1` from party #1 and `b2` from party #2.
These always have to come in pairs, with `output` first. In the real system we'd guarantee that by having a `Communicate` effect that got *handled into* `Input` and `Output`, but for now we'll just take it as an assumption.

I don't think it's possible to do the kind of parallel synchronous simulation I want entirely within the structure of a Polysemy handler (*aka* interpreter or runner). I'm pretty sure what I need is a function like

```hs
parallelEvaluation :: forall x a r.
                     (Sem r ([Pair x], a) -> Sem '[] ([Pair x], a)) ->
                     Pair (Sem (Output (Pair x) ': Input (Pair x) ': r) a) ->
                     Pair ([Pair x], a)
parallelEvaluation handleRest sems = ...
```

<sub>The first argument to `parallelEvaluation` is just a shim; I may not need it.</sub>

### The Idea:

If we imagine the two parties running in parallel, we can clearly gather up their `output`s as they send them; Polysemy has builtin handler just for that. That will give us exactly what we want: a list of all the messages sent.
The issue is what to feed into their `input`s.

The idea is the use the results of `parallelEvaluation` recursively as the input-tape to the `Input` handler. If the whole function is "sufficiently" lazy, and our above assumption that `output` and `input` always appear together is sound, then this should be computable.

**Polysemy *is* capable of the necessary laziness!**
Specifically see [here](https://github.com/ShapeOfMatter/polysemy-recusion/blob/a928a692ed9b911adc542c48d6f0a9215e3c676d/src/EarlyTests.hs). `doRealRecursion` *works fine*; the only special thing I did to make it work was use the `runLazyOutputList` handler (which isn't Polysemy's default for space-efficiency reasons).

### The Code:

#### [Testing the pure-parallel-simulation](https://github.com/ShapeOfMatter/polysemy-recusion/blob/a928a692ed9b911adc542c48d6f0a9215e3c676d/src/SndTests.hs):

```hs
import Polysemy (Members, Sem, reinterpret, run)
import Polysemy.Input (Input(Input), input)
import Polysemy.Output (Output, output, runLazyOutputList)
import Polysemy.State (get, put, runState)

import Pair (Pair(Pair),universe, (!))

runUnsafeInputList :: [i] -> Sem (Input i ': r) a -> Sem r a
-- Just like the normal PolySemy.Input.runInputList, except if there aren't enough inputs that's a runtime error!
runUnsafeInputList is = fmap snd . runState is . reinterpret (\case
    Input -> do ~(s : ss) <- get
                put ss
                pure s
    )

parallelEvaluation :: forall x a r.
                      (Sem r ([Pair x], a) -> Sem '[] ([Pair x], a)) ->
                      Pair (Sem (Output (Pair x) ': Input (Pair x) ': r) a) ->
                      Pair ([Pair x], a)
parallelEvaluation handleRest sems = run . handleRest <$> (runUnsafeInputList <$> os <*> (runLazyOutputList <$> sems))
  where os :: Pair [Pair x]
        os = fst <$> (parallelEvaluation handleRest sems)


testProgram :: forall r.
               Members '[Input (Pair String), Output (Pair String)] r =>
               Bool -> Sem r String
testProgram self = do output $ ((ownName ++ " says hi to ") ++) <$> parties
                      Pair m11 m12 <- input
                      let c1 = show $ (length m11) + (length m12)
                      output $ (++ ("; " ++ ownName ++ " got " ++ c1 ++ " characters last turn!")) <$> parties
                      Pair m21 m22 <- input
                      let c2 = show $ (length m21) + (length m22)
                      return $ ownName ++ "successfully got " ++ c2 ++ " characters in second round!"
  where parties = Pair "Party1" "Party2"
        ownName = parties ! self

doParallelRecursion :: IO ()
doParallelRecursion = do print "Attempting..."
                         let results = parallelEvaluation id $ testProgram <$> universe
                         print $ "Results: " ++ (show results)
```

#### [The `Pair` helper](https://github.com/ShapeOfMatter/polysemy-recusion/blob/a928a692ed9b911adc542c48d6f0a9215e3c676d/src/Pair.hs):

```hs
data Pair a where
  Pair :: a -> a -> Pair a
  deriving (Read, Show, Eq)
instance Functor Pair where
  fmap f (Pair a1 a2) = Pair (f a1) (f a2)
instance Applicative Pair where
  pure a = Pair a a
  (Pair f1 f2) <*> (Pair a1 a2) = Pair (f1 a1) (f2 a2)

(!) :: Pair a -> Bool -> a
(Pair a1 a2) ! b = if b then a2 else a1

universe :: Pair Bool
universe = Pair False True
```

### The Problem:

As an executable, `doParallelRecursion` prints `"Attempting..."` (with a newline), and then hangs (seemingly forever).

From GHCI, it prints

```
"Attempting..."
"Results:
```

and then hangs on that line for several seconds before `*** Exception: stack overflow`.

I've attempted to use the debugger in GHCI to narrow down the problem. Assuming I'm using it correctly, the bodies of `runUnsafeInputList` and `testProgram` aren't ever being evaluated. `runUnsafeInputList <$> os` evaluates `os`, which immediately recurses.

I've tried swapping the order of the effects/handlers, this didn't affect the behavior at all. (I don't think it ought to matter, but the order presented here may be more intuitive.)

Comment: Stripping out all the `fmap`s, you have `parallelEvaluation handleRest sems = parallelEvaluation handleRest sems <*> {- ... -}`. Seems clear to me why that can't work. Fixes include pattern matching on `sems` and actually doing something before you recurse, or explaining to the compiler why it should know that this first `(<*>)` can assume its argument is a `Pair` and therefore evaluation can proceed. (Perhaps making the patterns in `(<*>)`'s and `fmap`'s implementations irrefutable would work...?)